# Filter pandas dataframe if value is either 'True' or null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe

```
A    B     C
1    ABC   True
2    DEF   False
3    GHI
```

I would like to filter this dataframe and select those rows where column C is either 'True' or blank.

```
A    B     C
1    ABC   True
3    GHI
```

I tried many approaches and below is the latest effort but none of them are working.

```
df2= df.loc[df['C'] | df['C'].isnull()]
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: what is the value of the cell `df.loc[3, "C"]` ?

Comment: `df['C'].isin(['True',''])` or `df['C'].ne('False')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have only strings in column `C`. You can do:

```py
df = df[df.C.eq("True") | df.C.eq("")]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A    B     C
0  1  ABC  True
2  3  GHI
```